# How to show both text and icons in SWT Combo?

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I want to add both text and an image to the items of a `Combo` widget? Is this possible at all or are there alternatives?

Comment: The SWT Combo only supports  text

Comment: Why does this have 5 downvotes? Since Windows itself supports custom painting of Combos this question is completly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with the SWT `Combo` widget.

However, [Nebula](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/) has a widget called [`TableCombo`](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php) that can show an icon and a text in a combo-like form.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Stackoverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    TableCombo tc = new TableCombo(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);

    Image image = display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_ERROR);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TableItem ti = new TableItem(tc.getTable(), SWT.NONE);
        ti.setText("Item " + i);
        ti.setImage(image);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    shell.setCursor(display.getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_IBEAM));

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Varsha Download, unzip the libraries, add them to your library folder, re-build, run, success.

Comment: I got it. I used extended  SWT_AWT to use swing components in SWT.

Comment: @Varsha You really only should do that if you really need to. Mixing frameworks is not a decision you should take lightly.

Comment: @Var20: I also disapprove. Don't mix frameworks. Nebula isn't the nicest also, but at least you won't run into all these problems you get when mixing AWT and SWT.